# The DIVs are grouped and they are not going down when i add a text into each div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see on the snippet below, the `div` with the class `divSection` is grouped, those `div` should stay below the text (text 1, text 2, text 3) that are into the `div` with the class `divSection`. I could add a `margin` on `divSection`, but i want it to have 0 `margin` when there's no content into the `div`.

```css
.divSection3, .divSection7{
  height: 38px;
  background-color: rgba( 26, 26, 26, 0.7);
}
.section{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.section::before,
.section::after {
  content: "";
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.35);
  height: 1px;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12" style="background-color: red;">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="divSection3 col-lg-12">
          <div>
            <h6 class="section text-white ml-2 mr-2 ml-lg-0 mr-lg-0">Title 1</h6>
            <div>
              <h5>texto 1</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divSection7 col-lg-12">
          <div>
            <h6 class="section text-white ml-2 mr-2 ml-lg-0 mr-lg-0">Title 2</h6>
            <div>
              <h5>texto 2</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divSection3 col-lg-12">
          <div>
            <h6 class="section text-white ml-2 mr-2 ml-lg-0 mr-lg-0">Title 3</h6>
            <div>
              <h5>texto 3</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it should looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just remove the `height: 38px;` from the `.divSection3, .divSection7` selectors because it is redundant.

One more thing, you shouldn't have different names for the classes because the class purpose is to have multiple items selectable with one CSS rule. For unique elements rules you should use IDs instead of classes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

css:

```
.divSection {
  background-color: rgba( 26, 26, 26, 0.7);
}

h5 {
  background-color: red;
}

.u-padding-top {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.section{
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section::before,
.section::after {
  content: "";
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.35);
  height: 1px;
}
```

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12" style="background-color: red;">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="divSection col-lg-12 u-padding-top">
          <div>
            <h6 class="section text-white ml-2 mr-2 ml-lg-0 mr-lg-0">Title 1</h6>
            <div>
              <h5>texto 1</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divSection col-lg-12">
          <div>
            <h6 class="section text-white ml-2 mr-2 ml-lg-0 mr-lg-0">Title 2</h6>
            <div>
              <h5>texto 2</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divSection col-lg-12">
          <div>
            <h6 class="section text-white ml-2 mr-2 ml-lg-0 mr-lg-0">Title 3</h6>
            <div>
              <h5>texto 3</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

***UPDATED***
Took off redundancy